# How to change the heap size of a Hadoop map task within the java code?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As the following link says, the default value for a map task's heap size is 200 MB, however I need to increase it because I need to increase the `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` to at least 300 or 400MB. I don't have access to Hadoop config files in order to make such a change, so I has to do it in my code. How can I do that?

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Answer (score 5):

We can set the parameters through Configuration API.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "heap size here");
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

Also, mapred.child.ulimit should be 2–3x higher than the heap size specified in mapred.child.java.opts

Comment: are you sure it will work? as once the JVM is up and running, can one change heap space ? This would certainly change the config parameter's value but would it really get the JVM's instance more heap?

Comment: This is part of job configuration, Before mappers or reducers initialized or started. JVM will not be created for child tasks(map,reduce) at this step.It should work.

Comment: oops, got it, changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

In order to set/chnage hadoop configurations programmatically, you can have your driver class as follows:

```
    public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {


        @Override
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

                Configuration conf = getConf();

                conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Xmx1024m -Xss600m");
                conf.set("mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb", "400m");
...

    }
    }
```